# How to change the background colour of column header of a WPF datagrid without affecting other properties

Tags: wpf

The style used for column header :-

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <theme:DataGridHeaderBorder Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}"
                                 IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                 IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                 IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}"
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                 Padding ="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                 SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}"
                                 ContextMenu="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderContextMenu}"                        
                                 SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}">

                                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"   Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  FontWeight="Bold"  
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              Padding ="{TemplateBinding Padding}"                               
                                        TextWrapping="NoWrap"></TextBlock>
                        </theme:DataGridHeaderBorder>                          
                        <Thumb Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Thumb.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                                    <Style.Resources>
                                        <ResourceDictionary />
                                    </Style.Resources>
                                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <thumbConversion:Double>8</thumbConversion:Double>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Panel.Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <SolidColorBrush>#00FFFFFF</SolidColorBrush>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Cursor">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Cursor>SizeWE</Cursor>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" />
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Thumb.Style>
                        </Thumb>

                        <Thumb Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Thumb.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                                    <Style.Resources>
                                        <ResourceDictionary />
                                    </Style.Resources>
                                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <thumbConversion:Double>8</thumbConversion:Double>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Panel.Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <SolidColorBrush>#00FFFFFF</SolidColorBrush>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Cursor">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Cursor>SizeWE</Cursor>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" />
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Thumb.Style>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Before changing the Background color, the Column header looks like this.

[image]

I changed the Background color by adding

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template"> 
    ...........
```

It overrides everything I have specified in the template property. The sort symbols are not shown.

Then I tried adding the background color in the TextBlock part of the template. I changed the horizontal and vertical alignments to "Stretch" and provided the background color. The sort symbols are chopped and it looks ugly when I select the header.

[image]

I just want to change the background color. How do I do it?

Comment: Did setting the Background of your TextBlock  to be transparent help?

Comment: If I lower the opacity of the background, the background color is not seen.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the Background colour of the `DataGridHeaderBorder` without losing the sort arrows.

If you set the Background property you will have to create the sort arrows yourself in your custom template.

The default background that you see is actually drawn in the `OnRender` method of the `Microsoft.Windows.Themes.DataGridHeaderBorder` class. It is not defined in some XAML template.

Answer (score 0):

First in your DataGridView you need to set EnableHeadersVisualStyles to false. After you've done that you can set the individual header style on each column.

```
    DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
    dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
    dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: My question was for a WPF Datagrid view. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. I will edit the question.